# Can SQL STRING_SPLIT use two (or more) separators?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of drug names that are stored in various upper and lower case combinations. I need to capitalize the first letter of each word in a string, excluding certain words. The string is separated by spaces, but can also be separated by a forward slash.

The following code works:

```
create table #exclusionlist (word varchar(25))
create table #drugnames (drugname varchar(50))

insert into #exclusionlist values ('ER')
insert into #exclusionlist values ('HCL')

insert into #drugnames values ('DRUGNAME ER')
insert into #drugnames values ('drugname hcl')
insert into #drugnames values ('ONEDRUG/OTHERDRUG')

select  'Product Name'   = drugname
,       'Product Name 2' = STUFF((SELECT ' ' + 
                case when value in (select word from #exclusionlist) then upper(value)
                else upper(left(value, 1)) + lower(substring(value, 2, len(value))) end
                from STRING_SPLIT(drugname, ' ')
                FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'')
from #drugnames
```

The output looks like this:

```
Drugname ER
Drugname HCL
Onedrug/otherdrug
```

How can I get that last one to look like this:

```
Onedrug/Otherdrug
```

I did try `STRING_SPLIT(replace(drugname, '/', ' '), ' ')` but obviously replaces the slash with a space. And if the slash is at the end of the string like `ONEDRUG/OTHERDRUG/` then the result looks like `Onedrug Otherdrug&#x20;`

It's possible that the string may end in a forward slash due to the field only holding N number of characters. When data gets inserted into the table, only the first N characters of the drug name are inserted. If that Nth character is a slash, the string will end in a slash.

Comment: Also, creating a function is out of the question. The users don't have the rights to run functions.

Comment: Let us know what version of SQL Server you are using. My answer below assumed SQL 2017 or greater. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` expression for the `separator` parameter to the `STRING_SPLIT` function.

In the code below, a common table expression (CTE) uses `STRING_SPLIT` to split out all the drugname words and capitalize the first letter of each word as appropriate.

The CTE results are unioned together using `STRING_AGG` to join the drugnames back together. Note that separator parameter for `STRING_AGG` cannot be an expression. Using a `CASE` expression results in this error:

> Msg 8733, Level 16, State 1, Line 14 Separator parameter for
> STRING_AGG must be a string literal or variable.

For SQL Server, you would need to be on SQL 2017 or greater for the `STRING_AGG`  function. (I added an id/identity column to the #drugnames temp table to assist with grouping.)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #exclusionlist;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #drugnames;

CREATE TABLE #exclusionlist (word VARCHAR(25))
CREATE TABLE #drugnames (id INT IDENTITY, drugname VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #exclusionlist VALUES ('ER')
INSERT INTO #exclusionlist VALUES ('HCL')

INSERT INTO #drugnames VALUES ('DRUGNAME ER')
INSERT INTO #drugnames VALUES ('drugname hcl')
INSERT INTO #drugnames VALUES ('ONEDRUG/OTHERDRUG')
    
;WITH SomeStuff AS
(
    select  d.id, d.drugname,
        sp.value AS SplitValue, el.word AS ExclusionListSpaceWord, 
        COALESCE(el.word,
            UPPER(LEFT(sp.value, 1)) + LOWER(RIGHT(sp.value, LEN(sp.value) - 1))
        ) AS CapitalizedWord
    from #drugnames d
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(d.drugname, CASE WHEN d.drugname LIKE '%/%' THEN '/' ELSE ' ' END ) sp
    LEFT JOIN #exclusionlist el
        ON el.word = sp.value
)
SELECT ss.id, STRING_AGG(ss.CapitalizedWord, '/') AS ReconstructedDrugname 
FROM SomeStuff ss
WHERE ss.drugname LIKE '%/%'
GROUP BY ss.id
UNION
SELECT ss.id, STRING_AGG(ss.CapitalizedWord, ' ') AS ReconstructedDrugname 
FROM SomeStuff ss
WHERE ss.drugname LIKE '% %'
GROUP BY ss.id
```

**Output:**

```
id          ReconstructedDrugname
----------- ----------------------
1           Drugname ER
2           Drugname HCL
3           Onedrug/Otherdrug
```

Answer (score 0):

If the "/" is replaced to a " /", then the split can still happen on the space.
And the extra space can be removed afterwards.

> ```
> SELECT  
>   [Product Name]   = d.drugname
> , [Product Name 2] = ca.drugname2
> FROM #drugnames d
> CROSS APPLY (
>   SELECT 
>     REPLACE(LTRIM(x.value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')),' /','/') AS drugname2
>   FROM
>   (
>     SELECT ' '+
>       CASE
>       WHEN e.word IS NOT NULL THEN e.word
>       WHEN s.value LIKE '/%' 
>        THEN STUFF(LOWER(s.value),1,2,UPPER(LEFT(s.value,2)))
>       ELSE  STUFF(LOWER(s.value),1,1,UPPER(LEFT(s.value,1)))
>       END
>     FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(d.drugname,'/',' /'),' ') s
>     LEFT JOIN #exclusionlist e
>       ON e.word = s.value
>     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
>   ) q(x)
> ) ca;
> ```

> | Product Name | Product Name 2 |
> | --- | --- |
> | DRUGNAME ER | Drugname ER |
> | drugname hcl | Drugname HCL |
> | ONEDRUG/OTHERDRUG | Onedrug/Otherdrug |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b4704f0e66b6be350ed582001c052e92)*

Answer (score 0):

If (hopefully) using SQL 2017+ you can somewhat compact the logic. first a single string split by using *translate* to create a common separator. THen apply the exclude word criteria forllowed by the upper-case criteria, then re-aggregate, noting which separator to use.

```
select * 
from #drugnames
outer apply (
    select case 
        when max(sep)=' ' then String_Agg(word,' ')
        else String_Agg(word,'/') end NewName
    from (
        select 
            case
              when exists (select * from #exclusionlist x where x.word = value) 
              then Upper(value) 
              else Stuff(Lower(value),1,1,Upper(Left(value,1)))
            end word, Iif(drugname like '%/%','/',' ') sep
        from String_Split(Translate(drugname,' /','**'),'*')
    )w
)new;
```

[Example DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=86a01c03a9e99604d7e5c9b29d6a6380)

Output:

[image]

Note - using string_split *does not*, according to the documentation, guarantee the ordering of the values. In practice, I've never seen this be the case and since you're already using the function I'm using here also. There's plenty of ways to split the string while retaining an ordering (using json for example) should it ever prove necessary.

If you are still on 2016 then the string_agg can just be replaced with the *for xml* implementation you're already using.

Comment: I don't see why you would want to use TRANSLATE and introduce a third special character (*) that would cause problems if it already existed in the string . Vs just REPLACE all slahes with space then splitting on space